# start instance with persistent disk and specific disk name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a persistent disk named `foo` that I would like to attach to an instance I create. I run the following command

```
gcloud beta compute --project=myproject instances create myinstance --machine-type=n1-standard-4 --disk=device-name=foo,name=foo
```

However, when I look at the instances and run `sudo lsblk` the disk appears under name `sdb` instead of `foo`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device special is set by Linux and will always be `sd#` something. But it can change depending on the sequence that persistent disks are attached to the instance.

Setting an ID will cause a persistent link to be added in `/dev/disk/by-id` using that name that always refers to the disk. For instance, if you name the disk `foo` then you will get a link `/dev/disk/by-id/google-foo` which always points to the correct `sd#` device special. You can then use that link (and/or the corresponding partition links, after the disk is partitioned) to refer to the disk.

Comment: ha, won't let me upvote because my rep is < 15

Comment: That's ok, you'll get it soon!